# alt+tab is not working while switching from kde (vnc) to windows applications

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, vnc, kde

I have **kde** installed in my vnc. I want to switch windows applications and vnc using `alt+tab` shortcut. 
`alt_tab` is working fine to move from window applications to vnc, **but when I am trying to move from kde (or vnc) to windows applications, `alt+tab` is not working.**

Please point me, where to change the relevant settings in kde or vnc.

Thanks.

Edit:
I have found below shortcuts in KWin (KDE), but it only switches kde's local windows.
[image: KWin shortcuts]

Answer (score 1):

Find the thread [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/task-switcher-inside-vnc).

If you're using Ubuntu with Gnome, then you can modify the keyboard shortcut assigned to switching windows on VNC server side desktop.

You have to use the keyboard shortcut control panel.

Browse through **System** then **Preferences** then **Keyboard Shortcut**.

In the Keyboard Shortcut window, look for **Move Between Windows, Using a popup window**.

Change it to something that is not a shortcut on your **Windows** or on the VNC Server.

Comment: Thank you, @Kiname Cole. I have gone through a thread pointed by you, but I didn't find **Move Between Windows, Using a popup window** option in kde. For your reference, I have attached a screenshot of few shortcuts available in KDE.

Comment: I already tried this option. Here desktop is similar to workspace in linux. Actually I don't want to switch to another workspace, but to another windows application.

Comment: Are you able to switch from kde to windows by pressing Ctrl+F1 or Ctrl+F2?

Comment: Nope. It's not working. :(

Comment: I think it's Ctrl+F4, would you please give it a try and let me know?

Comment: hard luck...!!! not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have the below configuration

- GNOME on centos running VNC server
- RealVNC client on Mac Ventura

I had to disable 'pass special keys directly to VNC server' on my RealVNC client's Properties window -> Options tab.

(hover the mouse pointer near the top edge of the VNC client window to get a menu and the 'gear' icon opens the Properties window)

Comment: Welcome to superuser! You can add a screenshot to your answer instead of a description of the location of a menu item. A screenshot will be much more descriptive and easier to understand.